# Capybara: Test current path to page created object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

After creating new object should redirect to action show. How me check current path?

```
feature 'add lost pet' do
  given(:data) {attributes_for(:lost_pet)}

  background do
    visit  root_path
    click_on 'Register new lost pet'
  end

  scenario 'add new lost pet with valid data' do
    within '#new_lost_pet' do
      fill_in 'Name', with: data[:name]
      fill_in 'Type', with: data[:type]
      fill_in 'Breed', with: data[:breed]
      fill_in 'Gender', with: data[:gender]
      fill_in 'Size', with: data[:size]
      fill_in 'Colour', with: data[:colour]
      fill_in 'Age', with: data[:age]
      fill_in 'Age unit', with: data[:age_unit]
      fill_in 'Description', with: data[:description]
      fill_in 'Collar description', with: data[:collar_description]
      check 'Desexed', :checked
      check 'Microchipped', :checked
      fill_in 'Microchip number', with: data[:microchipped_number]
      select '2015', from: "lost_pet[date_missing(1i)]"
      select 'October', from: 'lost_pet[date_missing(2i)]'
      select '10', from: 'lost_pet[date_missing(3i)]'
      fill_in 'Rewald', with: data[:rewald]
      fill_in 'Image', with: data[:image]
      fill_in 'Adress lost', with: data[:adress_lost]

      click_on 'Create'
    end  

    expect(current_path).to eq lost_pet_path(????)


  end
```

For lost_pet_path i need id, but how me create id? Or how better check path in Capybara?

Answer (score 30):

```
expect(current_path).to eq ...
```

doesn't use Capybara's waiting behavior - which means since click_on is asynchronous (isn't waiting for anything on screen, or for the submit to complete) your test may be very flaky.  You're much better off using

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(expected_path)
```

since that will use Capybara's waiting behavior while checking for the expected path.

On top of that you have the issue that the LostPet object isn't yet created right after the click_on executes (asynchronous) so calling LostPet.last then will most likely return nil.  You have a couple of options here

Wait for some text thats going to appear on the page

```
expect(page).to have_text('Lost Pet created') # shows in a flash message, or header on the show page, etc
# since you know the show page is visible now you can query for the last LostPet created
expect(page).to have_current_path(lost_pet_path(LostPet.last))
```

or, use the  regex option with have_current_path and don't worry about verifying the actual id of the url

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(/lost_pet\/[0-9]+/) # match the regex to whatever your urls actually are
```

or something like that

Answer (score -1):

Since the created record is the most recent one in the database, `MyActiveRecordModel.last` can be used.

```
lost_pet = LostPet.last
expect(current_path).to eq lost_pet_path(lost_pet)
```

Comment: i added lost_pet = LostPet.last and get error: **Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq lost_pet_path(lost_pet)
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lost_pets", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]**

Comment: the asynchronous nature of click_on means the LostPet most likely won't have been created at this point (if using any driver other than rack-test) - so LostPet.last will be nil -- see my answer